# Add custom button to active admin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

Is it at all possible to add a custom button along side the submit and cancel button that is generated with f.actions in this case?

The documents state:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors # shows errors on :base
  f.inputs          # builds an input field for every attribute
  f.actions         # adds the 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons
link_to 'Preview', preview_my_admin_panel_posts_path(@post)
end
```

How could I add something here?

### Update

I have got my custom button to show now with this:

```
inputs 'Submit' do
  f.actions do
    f.action :submit
    f.action :cancel
    f.action :reset
    li do
      link_to 'Preview', preview_my_admin_panel_posts_path()
    end
  end
```

Now I can't seem to grab the form object and pass through the params for post, `title` and `comments`.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547726/how-to-add-button-to-activeadmins-index-page

Comment: @GaganGami no, because it only would create the action_item, which would be put on the right top of the page. It is not what OP is asking for

Answer (score 4):

Yea, it is possible.

define an [`action_item`](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource/action_items.rb#L27):

```
action_item only: %i(new edit) do
  link_to 'Preview', preview_my_admin_panel_posts_path(@post)
end
```

Ok, I think you could do the following:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors
  f.inputs
  f.actions do
    f.submit, as: :button, label: 'Optional custom label'
    f.cancel, as: :link # I think could converted to button as submit
    link_to 'Preview', preview_my_admin_panel_posts_path(@post)
  end
end
```

Comment: Will that then appear next to my submit and cancel buttons? And not outside the form?

Comment: I just realized, that it would not.. I am thinking of how to make it inline with submit/cancel buttons

Comment: unfortunately that does not work, doesnt even show up in the dom as being created, pretty stumped on this one

Comment: I'm a little closer now and have updated my question

Comment: I was also thinking about `div` or something like this. To access the object you would do `f.object`..

Comment: so f.object.title, or would i need to create a query string like `post: { title: f.object.title, comments: f.object.comments}`, though it would be better if i didnt have to do this wouldn't it ?

Comment: it depends on what params should be passed to the url helper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96341/discussion-between-richlewis-and-andrey-deineko).

Comment: should not have comma after submit e.g.  f.submit (as: :button, label: 'Optional custom label' )