# Multiple Save buttons with different redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can I offer two submit buttons on an active admin form that after update redirect to different locations?

Comment: is't form or just two buttons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the actions in the actions block, setting a name and value that will be passed into the parameters.

This will be available in the controller block you can also create in the admin file

```
f.actions do
  f.action :submit, :as => :button
  f.action :submit, :as => :button, label: 'Save and Next', button_html: {name: 'foo', value: 'bah'}
  f.action :cancel, :as => :link, label: 'Cancel', class: 'cancel', wrapper_html: {class: :cancel}
end


controller do
    def update
      @start = Start.find params[:id]
      update! do |format|
        format.html {
          if params['foo']
            if   @start.next
              redirect_to edit_admin_start_path(@start.next)
            else
              redirect_to admin_race_path(@start.race_id)
            end
          else
            redirect_to admin_race_path(@start.race_id)
          end
        }
      end
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply select your `redirect` based on the `commit` value in your `params`.

Comment: how can i add the extra buttons though?

Comment: Did you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947555/add-custom-button-to-active-admin-form?rq=1) or the [docs here](https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html)?